# How can seemingly-conflicting conditional statements be structured so both are evaluated properly?

Tags: c#, logic, conditional-statements

I have written a program that checks the colors of an object, and based on the results, sends a signal to the object to change colors, then checks the new colors, etc. Based on the HSL ranges of possible colors, a Colorless component is often misinterpreted as being Black, so I have to use the behavior pattern of the object to infer whether a component measured as Black should actually be Colorless (and vice-versa). I also have to check to ensure the object has indeed changed color from the previous state, because lag is possible. The statements I use for these two tasks, respectively, are...

```
if (scaleColorsValue != previousArrayValue + previouslySelectedPlay && (scaleColorsValue - previousArrayValue - previouslySelectedPlay) % 7 == 0) // If expected result is off by a multiple of seven
```

...and...

```
if (!areArraysEqual(previousArray, scaleColors))
```

...where `areArraysEqual()` returns `true` if and only if the object’s colors are the same as the previous measurement.

The problem is that if I place the color correction if statement inside the lag check if statement, the lag check will automatically pass when a Colorless component is interpreted as being Black, because that would cause it to be not equal to the previous measurement, but if I place the color correction if statement before the lag check to fix this problem, then

```
(scaleColorsValue - previousArrayValue - previouslySelectedPlay) % 7 == 0
```

will not resolve to the correct value when there is lag.

How can the code be altered to avoid this undesirable dilemma, so that both conditionals are evaluated correctly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace macroScopic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rn1_ = new Random();
        bool state = false;  // True means on, false means off
        string strategyFileText;

        double cost;
        double baseBet;

        OrderedColors[] previousArray = { OrderedColors.NULL, OrderedColors.NULL, OrderedColors.NULL, OrderedColors.NULL, OrderedColors.NULL, OrderedColors.NULL };
        int previouslySelectedPlay = 2;
        int consecutiveLagFailures = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (StreamReader strategyFile = new StreamReader("strategy.txt"))
            {
                strategyFileText = strategyFile.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            state = onOffButton.Checked;
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);

            cost = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            baseBet = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        }

        // Code

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (state)
            {
                takeTurn();
                delay(1700, 5200, 5, timer1);
            }
        }

        private void takeTurn()
        {
            /// Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Bitmap screenShot = takeScreenShot();

            // Code

            if (/*Code*/)
            {
                // Code to set values of scaleColors elements, based on screenshot

                int previousArrayValue = value(previousArray);
                int scaleColorsValue = value(scaleColors);

                if (previouslySelectedPlay == 0)
                {
                    for (int scale = 0; scale < scaleColors.Length; scale++)
                    {
                        scaleColors[scale] = OrderedColors.Colorless;
                    }
                }
                else if (previouslySelectedPlay == 2 || previouslySelectedPlay == 1 || previouslySelectedPlay == 3 || previouslySelectedPlay == 6)
                {
                    if (scaleColorsValue != previousArrayValue + previouslySelectedPlay && (scaleColorsValue - previousArrayValue - previouslySelectedPlay) % 7 == 0)  // If expected result is off by a multiple of seven
                    {
                        int numRequiredChanges = Math.Abs((scaleColorsValue - previousArrayValue - previouslySelectedPlay) / 7);
                        int numCompletedChanges = 0;
                        bool isDirectionBToC = true;

                        for (int scale = 0; scale < scaleColors.Length; scale++)
                        {
                            if (scaleColorsValue < previousArrayValue + previouslySelectedPlay)
                            {
                                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Colorless)
                                {
                                    scaleColors[scale] = OrderedColors.Black;
                                    numCompletedChanges++;
                                }

                                isDirectionBToC = false;
                            }
                            else if (scaleColorsValue > previousArrayValue + previouslySelectedPlay)
                            {
                                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Black)
                                {
                                    scaleColors[scale] = OrderedColors.Colorless;
                                    numCompletedChanges++;
                                }

                                isDirectionBToC = true;
                            }

                            if (numCompletedChanges >= numRequiredChanges)
                            {
                                if (isDirectionBToC == true)
                                {
                                    scaleColorsValue -= (7 * numCompletedChanges);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    scaleColorsValue += (7 * numCompletedChanges);
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text += previouslySelectedPlay + " was not a valid play.\r\n";
                }

                if (!areArraysEqual(previousArray, scaleColors) || consecutiveLagFailures >= 4)
                {
                    // Code

                    int selectedPlay = selectPlay(strats, scaleColors);

                    // Code

                    if (selectedPlay == 0 || selectedPlay == 1 || selectedPlay == 3 || selectedPlay == 6)
                    {
                        SendKeys.Send(selectedPlay.ToString());

                        Array.Copy(scaleColors, previousArray, previousArray.Length);
                        previouslySelectedPlay = selectedPlay;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBox1.Text += selectedPlay + " is not a valid play.\r\n";
                    }
                }
                else  // If there was lag
                {
                    // Code

                    takeTurn();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Code

                takeTurn();
            }
        }

        private Bitmap takeScreenShot()
        {
            // Code
        }

        private string rgbToHsl(int r, int g, int b)
        {
            // Code
        }

        private hslColor medianHSAndL(hslColor[] inputs)
        {
            // Code
        }

        // Retrieves the appropriate game play for the array of medians
        private int selectPlay(string[] strats, OrderedColors[] scaleColors)
        {
            // Code
        }

        private void delay(int min, int max, int maxDepth)
        {
            // Code
        }

        private void delay(int min, int max, int maxDepth, System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer)
        {
            // Code
        }

        private int value(OrderedColors[] scaleColors)
        {
            int numColorless = 0;
            int numPurple = 0;
            int numBlue = 0;
            int numGreen = 0;
            int numYellow = 0;
            int numOrange = 0;
            int numRed = 0;
            int numBlack = 0;
            int numNull = 0;

            for (int scale = 0; scale <= 5; scale++)
            {
                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Colorless)
                {
                    numColorless++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Purple)
                {
                    numPurple++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Blue)
                {
                    numBlue++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Green)
                {
                    numGreen++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Yellow)
                {
                    numYellow++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Orange)
                {
                    numOrange++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Red)
                {
                    numRed++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.Black)
                {
                    numBlack++;
                }

                if (scaleColors[scale] == OrderedColors.NULL)
                {
                    numNull++;
                }
            }

            if (numNull == 0)
            {
                return (7 * numBlack) + (6 * numRed) + (5 * numOrange) + (4 * numYellow) + (3 * numGreen) + (2 * numBlue) + numPurple;
            }
            else
            {
                return -2;
            }
        }

        private double reward(OrderedColors[] scaleColors)
        {
            // Code
        }

        private bool areArraysEqual<T>(T[] array1, T[] array2)
        {
            Array.Sort(array1);
            Array.Sort(array2);

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(array1, array2))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array1[i].Equals(array2[i]) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class hslColor
    {
        // Code
    }

    public class hslRange
    {
        // Code
    }

    public enum OrderedColors
    {
        Colorless,
        Purple,
        Blue,
        Green,
        Yellow,
        Orange,
        Red,
        Black,
        NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't.  If both computations require the result of the other to work, then you can't compute either.  You'll need to find a different way of computing one of these values that removes the dependency on the other.

Comment: This question needs to be simplified.  That code sample is too long for me to want to dive into it.  What is the magic number 7? Are the colors changing based on some rules (how do you know if it's misinterpreted?)